# Can't parse json into JArray object after using JSON_ARRAY and JSON_OBJECT in mysql

Tags: c#, mysql, json, json.net

I'm querying a mySQL (MariaDB) database and use **JSON_ARRAY and JSON_OBJECT** to gather json objects as array.

I have an api to retrieve the data from the DB, by using GetAsync.

Afterwards, in the api consumer, I want to parse the Json into an object,
using JArray (Newtonsoft).

I can't manage to parse the Json due to problem in the JSON_OBJECT (it seems like a quote wrapping the array sign "["). See error code below.

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it ?

When getting another Json from another data source (not using JSON_ARRAY and JSON_OBJECT), parsing is working (see example below)

This is my code:

```
public JARrray parse(HttpResponseMessage response)
{
    return JArray.Parse(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result); 
}
```

This is the string that **works**:

```
[
    {
        "remark":"",
        "driver": [
            {
                "username":"0000000",
                "uid":"00000000",
                "fname": "000000",
                "lname": ""
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

And this is the string that get the message

> After parsing a value an unexpected character was encountered: u. Path '[0].driver', line..."

I can see in the stack that this is happening on the line:

```
JsonTextReader.ParsePostValue(Boolean ignoreComments):
```

Json:

```
[
    {
        "remark":"",
        "driver": "[{\"username\": \"0000000\", \"uid\": \"00000000\", \"fname\":\"ZZZZZ\", \"lname\":\"\"}]"
    }
]
```

or even, when I removing the "" :

```
[
    {
        "remark":"",
        "driver": "[{"username": "0000000", "uid": "00000000", "fname":"ZZZZZ", "lname":""}]"
    }
]
```

Comment: You say you are getting the data from a database, but in your parse method you are using `HttpResponseMessage`. Also in your first json structure `driver` is an array, whereas in your second block it's a string containing a json encoded array.

Comment: @derpirscher - I have an API creator  which generates an api and I get the response as a string (used it with other data soures). As for your  comment regarding the driver string containing a json encoded array - You are right ! How can I manage\fix it ?

Comment: The only proper way to fix this, is to store and retrieve the data correctly to/from the database and handle it correctly in your API creator.

Answer (score 0):

```
\"fname\":"\ZZZZZ\"
```

The escaped double quote in front of ZZZZZ is wrong. Change it from `"\` to `\"`.

Comment: This is a  typo error - when copied (free handed). I'll fix it